# Dialog box works only once

Tags: jquery, click, dialog

When I'm using the below code, the dialog box run only once. Why?

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr id="header">
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Surname</td>
        <td>Message</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name 1</td>
        <td>Surname 1</td>
        <td id="tikla1">Click Here!
            <div id="dialog-message" title="12.07.2015" style="display: none">Msg 1: lorem ipsum</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name 2</td>
        <td>Surname 2</td>
        <td id="tikla2">Click Here!
            <div id="dialog-message" title="12.07.2015" style="display: none">Msg 2: dolor sit amet
                <br>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#tikla1,#tikla2").click(function () {
    $(this).children("#dialog-message").dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
table, td {
    border:1px solid;
}
#header {
    font-weight: bold;
}
#tikla:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    color:red;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qP8DY/3100/)

Comment: You should include the jQuery code in your question here on StackOverflow. Otherwise it's not even clear what code is executing only once without checking the fiddle link.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: improved grammar
added tag

Comment: you can also try this http://jsfiddle.net/qP8DY/3106/

Comment: I have added the full code into the question to prevent link rot issues and have removed library name from title as it is not required due to presence of tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of issues in your code:

1. The IDs must be unique. Change the `#dialog-message` to `.dialog-message`.
2. You need to initialize the dialog first and then call it, initialize it with `autoOpen: false`:

   ```
   $("#tikla1, #tikla2").children(".dialog-message").dialog({
       modal: true,
       autoOpen: false,
       buttons: {
           Ok: function() {
               $( this ).dialog( "close" );
           }
       }
   });
   ```
3. You need to have a separate calling function.

   ```
   $( "#tikla1, #tikla2" ).click(function() {
       $(this).children(".dialog-message").dialog("open"); 
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot i need exactly this id s must unique, use classes my new code here http://jsfiddle.net/qP8DY/3114/